# Mac doesn't show right information in Storage

Tags: macos, icloud, memory, storage

For some reason my Mac doesn't show a space taken by iCloud. I have 0.8 of 5.0 gb available on it, but it doesn't show a blue section. I used to have it. What can I do to return it? [image]

Comment: The answer by Tetsujin is where you should be checking your iCloud storage at, but the reason it's not in the photo you added is because macOS isn't (done) indexing your SSD.

Answer (score 1):

iCloud storage isn't included in your Mac's storage at all - because it isn't on your Mac.
It's in a separate area in System Preferences > iCloud…

[image]

Comment: No. You wrong. I agree about "iCloud isn't on my Mac", but I used to have this blue section. It disappeared about 6 days ago.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm a bit disappointed - I expected to see something like this: [icloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hfnwc.png)

Comment: @klanomath - LOL, nice one ;-)))